# How to resolve "X was reduced to 'never' because property 'Y' has conflicting types in some constituents" in this TypeScript example?

Tags: typescript

I have a fairly large compiler project I'm working on, and have copied out the relevant TypeScript portions into [this TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgGYFcB2BjOBLKaEYwgCGcIAciAM5wA8AKguGWgCZUKU0B8AFMAgQAbbAGsQALgT0ANAIRUMUCJIQBlbGTVkIapSvoBPFXICUUrnCMqG3BAG95ROChj5HgwRgAW2IayI0KQBtAF05T2ExEAjPRWUY+QBfYBTQSFhEEDQUAFt1TRAHeW0QXX0igF4EAHIqQoBaGjKmipq5NPBoeAQ4YyKNLR09BOsq4sFWEAwhYhhSXDQqKQAladhWWhoYbDQAcxkCsgA1OexiACMhEAARadn5nDwx7nkRcSlBkAA6UvKE+QQIgAN1wKCoAH5PoU-iMDP1UsB0t1EH0VEcQKcdpdrncZnMFs9+ghqh4oh8FHAdvtEcjMkwcvlLBMEABBKhUEDwRYkhAAIjQ1DgDWIHK5TzQfNiACFdqxeQKhQ0LnKpbSuvS0UVLNLRSAxryyT4-AFslJWTB5oZaJYxjahXYAD4IACy1G8drdVG83G4AG55PEVNChmU4fr+gHOhkelrOEL2ZzuUT0dUdXqDQAyFnvVSWb6J8WLdUx1HE239BhMMAsdjxni8ywu4gQCC7PZjYL0UJIjU9bJ5V3ulmF5P4ao1XLukVisftEso3rEr3eUcSg3VFe6zlZlkqtjmy3Ea3oURoKAAdzQr0EuakK4Ls4l8jQxCnUm27YXmuX7u3EdTPcoHQVgoQQC4oCga5iDQQMKjAr5YQqMZv1jX9vWbVt2w3FlJ2nUUkwlGp73dNdFhQ6NFzjFc7UYZhsjrFc7E3d1MLbfZO27JEAHpuIQBoBKROk0PRHU5Rw9Md2JbMyTves4G+WU2CjANhLLUShTY7DiVJeRFRoGdCMWPkLATJ9yMjPTBQM-dWBM+SlNYMYVOAIA) (it's a lot of types, which I think might be part of the problem).

The function at the top is this, which is throwing an error:

```
export function createNest<T extends Nest>(
  like: T,
  scope: SiteStepScopeType,
): NestType<T> {
  return {
    children: [],
    like,
    scope,
  }
}
```

It is throwing:

```
Type '{ children: never[]; like: Nest; scope: SiteStepScopeType; }' is not assignable to type 'NestType<T>'.
  Type '{ children: never[]; like: Nest; scope: SiteStepScopeType; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    The intersection 'NestBaseType & { like: Nest.Assertion; } & { like: Nest.Bind; } & SiteModuleBaseType & { like: Nest.BookModule; } & { like: Nest.Boolean; } & { like: Nest.BorrowVariable; } & ... 31 more ... & { ...; }' was reduced to 'never' because property 'like' has conflicting types in some constituents.(2322)
```

Basically:

> ...was reduced to 'never' because property 'like' has conflicting types in some constituents

I checked `like` on the `Nest*` types, and they all have a relevant value, I can't see anything that could be wrong. Is it because I have so many types? Or what is it exactly that's wrong?

Comment: I don't know, maybe after I get some sleep I'll feel like wading through hundreds of lines of code, but maybe not.  If you have any way of reducing that to a [mre] you're more likely to get useful engagement.  Also, the code example should be included as plaintext in the question, not only available in an external link... if it doesn't fit, that's another indication that you should be reducing the code example size.

Comment: @jcalz Ok I have trimmed it down a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is rather confusing, but the problem the compiler doesn't understand the case where one of the values in `Nest` is not a key of the `NestMappingType` type. To my knowledge, there is no way to specify this relationship, but you can inform the compiler what's happening by using an additional constraint on `T` in `createNest` and a type assertion, like so;

```js
export function createNest<T extends keyof NestMappingType & Nest>(
  like: T,
  scope: SiteStepScopeType,
): NestType<T> {
  return {
    children: [],
    like,
    scope,
  } as NestType<T>
}
```

If you prefer, instead of the additional type constraint you could also redefine `Nest` like this:

```js
enum NestMappingKey {
  Assertion = "nest-assertion",
  Bind = "nest-bind",
}

export type Nest = NestMappingKey & keyof NestMappingType;
```